# Tab hot-key in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

One of the reason, why love Eclipse is hot-key tab;

jumping to the next without using Arrow key.

Example,

```
this.someKindOfMethod("some args");
```

As you all know, in here, if i open "" and type something and press tab it goes to ).

But sometimes, i don't know the reason, it doesn't do this feature and

"" becomes "     "

.....SAD :(

My question is, is there any hot-key to do tab feature in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the eclipse auto-close feature when you type `(` it will automatically add a `)` the same for `"` if it auto generates an auto-close feature pressing tab will push you to after the auto-close.
If you press tab any other time it will be treated as pressing tab as it is not connected to the auto-close feature.

Auto-close can be found at `Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing`

Comment: THanks for the tip. But my problem is, even theautoclose is applied some times the tab doesn't jump to the next step. So, this is just a eclipse bug :(

Comment: You should see a green bar appear on the other side of the autoclose whenever an autoclose is performed, when you see this, that is where the cursor will navigate to when you press tab. This will happen every time autoclose is called. I am unaware of any bug to do with this, please clarify the case in which this feature does not happen.

Comment: Thank you anyway :) I'm using a lot of plug-in, aptana, pdt, etc....Java always works fine, but other editors sometimes mass this.